# Delegate ontouch event to onclick listener js

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch-event

I have a page, that works perfectly on regular computer, but doesn't work correctly on tablet devices.
The trouble is that I'm using inline onclick handlers and they don't get fired on touch.

How can I extend regular onclick event without refactoring the whole page to call the same functions ontouch or onclick (but not twice).

I have multiple elements like this:

```
<button onclick="alert('OK')"></button>
```

How can I make them work without adding ontouch handler to each of them?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, that seems to work for me, but I'm not sure about it. 
I just trigger click event on touch, canceling default behavior.

It seems to work for any kind of click handlers, inline and passed to jQuery .click()

```
$(document).on('touchstart', function(event){
        event.target.click();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```